# Why typescript works differently on plain functions and react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

First, code:

```js
type Block = {blockName: string}
type Parsers = Record<string, (block: Block) => object>
type Renders<T> = {[key in keyof T]: (props: ReturnType<T[key] extends Parsers[string] ? T[key] : never>) => string}

const Blocks = <P extends Parsers>(props: {
  parsers: P
  renders: Renders<P>
}) => {
  return null
}
```

And its works fine on vanilla js [image]
But if call its as react component, suggestions for props of renders item doesn`t works [image]

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJyMkm)

Comment: I get the same errors on both snippets. See https://tsplay.dev/WKyMZN Please create [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @AlexWayne thanks for comment. https://tsplay.dev/WJyMkm

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your code does not work since I find it quite confusing and overly complicated. Simplifying the whole thing does solve the problem though.

```
type Block = { blockName: string }

const Blocks = <P extends Record<string, any>>(props: {
  parsers: Record<string, (arg: Block) => P>,
  renders: Record<string, (arg: P) => string>
}) => {
  return null
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAIQBsI0BrOAXjgG8AjJ1gHIoQSAFxwAzjCjAAdgHMAvuTQRZU+vxYSOcADwAFOEgAeMJLIAmO5KqiW9UmQoA0cFLMoA+LwAowOGAS4lykcHBgKFASSNHittAOTnLybr5R8uKMzCwAlBxecAZeLmFwRFaxwYhIdknSKWkZ4gb57IXJCl6kim2FoeFEMACuULJwssMMDD3k2awSvgPhEVExcdx2YnC+fDl9O1yywtsABsciogAkvFoAdHuCJ4qnvYqlK+UWllUhW+L+QISA6nG4BCBBO4XJAvZS9FRqDQAFSQGk4vgOy0GSBGY30820cDKn3CkWiVXYXC4-x2jzyBUO0PE5xO11uOQeWiEIlhuUUyhJKwqP2ilOp0G2gIhwIZoK44Mh0NhApWAHpCkTFEA)

Comment: Has one bug, try to add render with non-exist parser, its was has same props as any previous parser, my point is each render accepts props only from its parser.
[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NdAqYm)